# Receiving memory warning when downloading multiple files with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, memory-management, afnetworking-2

I am downloading movie files from UIGridViewCells. My code is:

```
NSMutableURLRequest* rq = [[APIClient sharedClient] requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:[[self item] downloadUrl] parameters:nil];
    [rq setTimeoutInterval:5000];
    _downloadOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:rq] ;
    _downloadOperation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:[[self item] localUrl] append:NO];
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [_downloadOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Successfully downloaded file to %@", [weakSelf.item localUrl]);
        [Helper saveItemDownloaded:weakSelf.item.productId];
        weakSelf.isDownloading = NO;
        [weakSelf.progressOverlayView removeFromSuperview];
        [weakSelf setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        [weakSelf.progressOverlayView removeFromSuperview];
        [weakSelf setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        weakSelf.isDownloading = NO;
        }];
    [_downloadOperation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
        float progress = totalBytesRead / (float)totalBytesExpectedToRead;
        weakSelf.progressOverlayView.progress = progress;
    }];
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:_downloadOperation];
```

And the property in ItemCell is:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) AFHTTPRequestOperation *downloadOperation;
```

After 1-2 successful downloads(20mb), I am receiving Memory Warning. Memory using is increasing with each download, and never decrease when the download finishes.

[image]

From Instruments:
[image]

Comment: Are you doing all this inside for loop ?

Comment: For download operations, yes. But I send a list to play movies.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the preferred method of downloading files with AFNetworking is by setting the "outputStream" property.

According to AFNetworking documentation:

> The output stream that is used to write data received until the request is finished.
>
> By default, data is accumulated into a buffer that is stored into `responseData` upon completion of the request. When `outputStream` is set, the data will not be accumulated into an internal buffer, and as a result, the `responseData` property of the completed request will be `nil`. The output stream will be scheduled in the network thread runloop upon being set.

I was having the same problem, solved it by using "outputStream".

Answer (score 0):

Use @autorelease per file downloaded:

```
for(File* file in fileList)
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        [self downloadFile:file];
    } 
}
```

This will release all variables and data allocated between separate files you download.

Also you should track down those memory leaks. I see some visible in instruments screenshots.

Comment: When I track memory leaks, I couldn't see any of them related to my code. I updated my question, please check.